# How to use modular headers configuration for pod dependency of my pod framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, podspec

My podspec looks like this:

```rb
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'flutter_vlc_player'
  s.version          = '0.0.3'
  s.summary          = 'A new Flutter project.'
  s.description      = <<-DESC
A new Flutter project.
                       DESC
  s.homepage         = 'http://example.com'
  s.license          = { :file => '../LICENSE' }
  s.author           = { 'Your Company' => 'email@example.com' }
  s.source           = { :path => '.' }
  s.source_files = 'Classes/**/*'
  s.public_header_files = 'Classes/**/*.h'
  s.dependency 'Flutter'

  s.dependency 'MobileVLCKit', '~> 3.3.10'
  s.static_framework = true

  s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'
end
```

How can I set the `:modular_headers => true` for the `s.dependency 'MobileVLCKit', '~> 3.3.10'` ? I tried to use like

```
s.dependency 'MobileVLCKit', '~> 3.3.10', :modular_headers => true
```

In the same way I would do in podfile, but it didn't work.

I know that I could use `'DEFINES_MODULE' => 'YES'` in the `pod_target_xcconfig`, however it did not fix the problem with non-modular header, because of the `MobileVLCKit` dependency.

Comment: What exactly is the modular header issue? I don't think there is a modular headers option for podspecs.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: @Yun I haven't found any solution. But, It seems to be more an issue of the VLCKit other than the cocoapods itself.